# Adjusting R Markdown Title Position in PDF output

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I am creating an R Markdown report and can´t find a way to move my title down the page.

Here is a minimal example, where I would like to move the title down 5cm:

```
---
title: "This is my title to display at 5cm below the top"
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
---

\thispagestyle{titlepage}
```

The `header.tex` file include some custom styling:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{titlepage}{
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
    \fancyfoot[LE,LO]{Project}
    \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo.png}} 
    }
```

**Output**:
[image]

Note that I´m not talking about the margins, just want to move the title so that it is not always at the top of the page.

Comment: By the way, forgot to mention that i have tried the following without success: 

\vspaces*{5cm}
\thispagestyle{title page}

Comment: you should post this as an answer if this is what you were looking for. Note that for this kind of customization, you'd better write your own [template](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#advanced-customization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
\setlength{\headsep}{5cm}
\thispagestyle{title page}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. You may [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) your own answer to mark the question as resolved.

Comment: @david, Where do you put those 2 lines ? inside the yaml ?

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to use the `titling` LaTeX package which makes it easy to change the styles of the titles. I have included some customisation inline within the `header-includes` argument of the YAML:

```
---
title: "This is my title to display at 5cm below the top"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{titling}
  - \setlength{\droptitle}{5em} 
---

# Content
And then something here...

\newpage

# Next Page
Some more text
```

[image]

> Including the LaTeX commands in the YAML is generally okay for small edits like this, but if you want to make further customisations I would recommend keeping them in an a separate `.tex` file as explained in the [R Markdown Definitive Guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html#advanced-customization-1)