# How to pass a title from Shiny application to R Markdown document?

Tags: r, shiny, yaml, r-markdown, pandoc

I have a shiny app with R Markdown report. I'm trying to pass the title via R to YAML in the `.Rmd` file.

**Simplified Shiny App**:

```
library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("test"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("p", "Project Name", "Project Name"),
      downloadButton("report")
    ),

    mainPanel(
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  tex_pn <- reactive({paste("Project Name:",input$p)})

  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "report.pdf",
    content = function(file) {
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      params <- list(pn=input$p)
      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }
  )

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**report.Rmd**:

I did the following in `.Rmd` file which does not work:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document :
    keep_tex: true
    number_sections: true
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
params <- list()
params$set_title <- tex_pn()
```
---
title: `r params$set_title`
author: "myname"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
---

some text `r params$pn`
````

the error is : `Warning: Error in tex_pn: could not find function "tex_pn"`.

I have also tried changing `params$set_title <- tex_pn()` to `params$set_title <- params$pn`, which creates a file but does not show any title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is not necessarily how your shiny app is configured, but more how the parameters are being specified in the report. You should create the `params` in the YAML frontmatter, with the title being specified **after** the parameters, as highlighted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861569/setting-document-title-in-rmarkdown-from-parameters):

```
---
author: "myname"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
params:
  set_title: test
title: "`r params$set_title`"
output: pdf_document
---

# Content
And then something here...
```

You can then control the document parameters within the `render` function as follows:

```
rmarkdown::render("report.Rmd",
                  params = list(set_title = "Some Text"),
                  envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))
```

[image]

> It would be worth reading the section on [parameterized report](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html) in the *R Markdown Defintive Guide* to find more about parameterized reports in R Markdown.

Comment: Would be great if you could help me with another question : How could I specify the title position in Rmarkdown? the following answer did not help since it changes all the other page as well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950851/rmarkdown-title-position

Answer (score 0):

This could work, if you add the r code in fron of the YAML header like this

````
---
output:
  pdf_document :
    keep_tex: true
    number_sections: true
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
params <- list()
params$set_title <- paste("Report from", date())
```

---
title: `r params$set_title`
author: "myname"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
---

# Content
And then something here...
````

I am not sure, though, if this is legit, but at least for me it works. As example I just paste some string with the current date, but there you would have then your `textInput`.

Comment: I have updated my question based on your answer! It is more clear now !