# RMarkdown. How to reduce space between title block and start of body text

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I've been using RMarkdown via RStudio on a Mac successfully.

Recently upgraded to RStudio 1.2.5019 and tinytex_0.18 and now the vertical spaceing between my "title block" and "first body text / heading" has increased.

Simple example, (deliberately excluding `author:` and `date:`), is:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document
title: "Example of Title to Body Text"
subtitle: Subtitle Places Here
---
This is the first paragraph (or heading if specified as such). It is quite a way down from the title of the document. How can this be reduced to a "single line" vertical space?

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
```

I then tried to use the "titlesec" package, but haven't been able to work out which command to use to achieve the desired outcome. Example of attempt is:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document

subparagraph: yes
header-includes: |
  \usepackage{titlesec}
  \titlespacing{\title}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}

title: "Example of Title to Body Text"
subtitle: Subtitle Places Here
---
This is the first paragraph (or heading if specified as such). It is quite a way down from the title of the document. How can this be reduced to a "single line" vertical space?

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
```

This is what it currently looks like rendered to PDF.

[image: Current output]

This is what I would like the PDF to look more like (edit from graphics program).

[image: Desired output]

So, how can I reduce this vertical spacing between the title block and the start of the document's body?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can reduce the space between the (sub)title and the first paragraph by adding `\vspace{}` command from LaTeX right before the first paragraph.

```r
---
output: 
  pdf_document

subparagraph: yes
header-includes: |
  \usepackage{titlesec}
  \titlespacing{\title}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}

title: "Example of Title to Body Text"
subtitle: Subtitle Places Here
---

\vspace{-5truemm}


This is the first paragraph (or heading if specified as such). It is quite a way down from the title of the document. How can this be reduced to a "single line" vertical space?

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks! This has worked just as I needed.

Comment: Happy to hear your success! Well,don't forget to upvote, too, hahaha

Answer (score 2):

For others who are also trying to move both the title and body text upward:

I do not understand what the two lines that [paulr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59640925/13716814) shared are doing:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\title}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
```

But I found another solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51617249), which uses the package of `titling`, and then moves the title up by `\setlengh{\droptitle}{5em}`.

After title is done, you can move the body text up using [carlos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59683461/13716814).

Comment: @paulr tried to reduce the space between title of an article and the contents by applying [titlesec](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) package. However, the command `\titlespacing{\title}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}` is in vain because the package does not support the spacing handling of the title of the article. The package only deals with the spacing around the `\section`, `\subsection`... and so on.

Comment: In case confusing to anyone why they are getting "undefined control sequence" error, there is a slight typo, should be: `\setlength{\droptitle}{5em}` .  It's subtle enough to miss upon reading :)  Also, if you want to move the title up, rather than down on the page, make this value negative, i.e. `\usepackage{titling}`  `\setlength{\droptitle}{-5em}` . This solution works nicely for this usecase, thanks @Hongtao Hao